# magento indexcontroller cache issue

Tags: cache, custom, index

We built a controller module that extends the Mage_Cms_IndexController and detects when certain no-route conditions are met, changes the handle and loads the new page

```
$update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
$this->loadLayout();
$update->addHandle('specialpage_result_index');
$this->loadLayoutUpdates();
$this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();        
$this->renderLayout();
```

The controller works perfectly, detects the conditions it needs and handles the load to the special page. A problem happens when we turn on the "LAYOUT_GENERAL_CACHE_TAG" (Layout) caching and it never renders our new page. We get a default blank CMS page instead of our targeted page. The issue obviously has something to do with the caching on the site, but we cannot figure out how to load the page each time without the cache affecting it. Can someone please let us know how to load the page without the caching affecting it? We have tried adding the noCache keys into the local.xml file, however that does not work either.